# Querying database with single user input in a web form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the following code to query my database but the page shows blank!

I can't see where the problem is! Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extract Student Data</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<?php
    include 'db.inc';

    // Show all student data in a <table>
    function displayStudentsList($connection,$query,$Year)
    {
        // Run the query on the DBMS
        if (!($result = @ mysql_query ($query, $connection)))
        showerror( );

        // Find out how many rows are available
        $rowsFound = @ mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If the query has results ...
        if ($rowsFound > 0)
        {
        // ... print out a header
        echo "Students data Of Year $Year<br>";

        // and start a <table>.
        echo "\n<table>\n<tr>" .
        "\n\t<th>Admission No.</th>" .
        "\n\t<th>Last Name</th>" .
        "\n\t<th>First Name</th>" .
        "\n\t<th>Gender</th>" .
        "\n\t<th>Orphan</th>" .
        "\n\t<th>District</th>\n</tr>";

        // Fetch each of the query rows
        while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        // Print one row of results
        echo "\n<tr>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["Admission"] . "</td>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["last_name"] . "</td>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["first_name"] . "</td>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["Gender"] . "</td>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["Orphan"] . "</td>" .
        "\n\t<td>" . $row["District"] . "</td>" .
        "\n</tr>";
        } // end while loop body

        // Finish the <table>
        echo "\n</table>";
        } // end if $rowsFound body

        // Report how many rows were found
        echo "$rowsFound records found matching your
        criteria<br>";
    } // end of function

    $scriptName = "combined.php";

    // Has the user provided the parameter?
    if (empty($Year))
    {
        // No, the user hasn't provided a parameter
    ?>
        <form action="<?=$scriptName;?>" method="GET">
        <br>Enter Year Of Admission :
        <input type="text" name="Year" value="All">
        (type All For All Years)
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Show Data">
        </form><br>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <?php
    } // end of if empty($Year) body
    else
    {
        // Secure the user parameter $Year
        $Year = clean($Year, 30);

        // Connect to the MySQL DBMS
        if (!($connection = @ mysql_connect($hostName, 
             $username,
             $password)))
        die("Could not connect");

        if (!mysql_select_db($databaseName, $connection))
        showerror( );

        // Start a query ...
        $query = "SELECT   Admission,  
        last_name,
        first_name,
        Gender,
        Orphan,
        District
        FROM     osasaasasaalumni_index;"

        // ... then, if the user has specified a year,
        // add the Year as an AND clause ...
        if ($Year != "All")
        $query .= " AND year = \"$Year\"";

        // ... and then complete the query.
        $query .= " ORDER BY last_name";

        // run the query and show the results
        displayStudentsList($connection, $query, $Year);

        // Close the DBMS connection
        mysql_close($connection);
    } // end of else if empty($Year) body
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

My db.inc is

```
<?
    $hostName = "xxxxxx";
    $databaseName = "xxxxx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";
?>
```

Whats wrong with the code because when I call it, it displays a blank page?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons. Enable error reporting by `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top if you haven't yet.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code, like this one: `@ mysql_connect` it should be `@mysql_connect`

Comment: You shouldn't suppress errors at all.

Comment: why you are supressing errors ..its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` at the end of this statement:

Original:

```
$query = "SELECT   Admission,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    Gender,
    Orphan,
    District
    FROM     osasaasasaalumni_index;"
```

Updated:

```
$query = "SELECT   Admission,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    Gender,
    Orphan,
    District
    FROM     osasaasasaalumni_index;";
```

If you see a blank page and no errors, then you should turn on error reporting. It can be done for example by putting this code in the beginning of your script, right after `<?php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```